# Replace toast message with startActivity for gridArray index

Tags: android

I am currently struggling with setting OnItemClickListener relevant to the item being clicked in my gridView.

The following code prints out the index location of each item. But instead, I want it to start a new activity, depending on which item is clicked.

```
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridview.setAdapter(new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, 0, gridArray));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(NonIllustratedHolder.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I obviously need to create a startActivity for each index, but how would I code this? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: according to the position put the if conditions and start your activity's

Comment: Could you give me an example? I am familiar with referencing indexes in python programming, but not yet java. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
gridview.setAdapter(new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, 0, gridArray));

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(NonIllustratedHolder.this, "" + position,      
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // function call the activity according to index
        startActivity(position); 
    }
});
```

function start the activity

```
public void startActivity(int index)
    {
        if(index==0)
        {
               //startFirstActivity
        }
        else if(index==1)
        {
               //startSecondActivity
        }
        //so on upto the number of item you have
    }
```